# Forwarding ports of a mobile hotspot to local server

Tags: port, forwarding

I will start with thanking you for your kind answer.

We are currently doing a project entitled "IoT based surveillance system". We are using Raspberry Pi 3B to stream the video feed on a local port, and later accessing the same port on the internet via port forwarding.

But the problem is we can't use a router. We are using a Mobile Hotspot Tethering (From an android device) to create the local network, because of which we are unable to change the port forwarding rules of our router (Mobile Hotspot).

Please help me with a way we can access the ports of Raspberry over the internet.

Thanks again.

Comment: The way I've done this from behind NAT out to the world or other subnets behind the NAT is to use a UDP stream from the Pi/broadcast device out to a server on the internet, and then re-broadcast/reflect the stream to various clients.  I've done this using Wowza, Darwin Streaming Server, and the built-in streaming server that VLC provides.

Comment: IPv6 is the solution, of course, but it's possible that your Android device doesn't support IPv6 on tethering, or your mobile carrier doesn't, or both.